# Find a balanced Neighborhood

Tags: code-golf, balanced-string

Your task will be to take a [balanced-string](/questions/tagged/balanced-string) and a integer representing a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (the number of characters that have to be inserted, deleted or changed to make one string into another) and you must find the number of balanced strings with that distance from the original string (i.e. the neighborhood of that string).

### Stipulations

- Balanced strings will consist only of the characters `()<>[]{}`
- You will only be asked to find neighborhoods for positive even distances
- Input and output is flexible.  As long as you take in all the proper data and output the correct answer without violating any loopholes I am happy with your answer.
- You may choose to divide all of your integer inputs by 2 if you choose.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the objective is to minimize the number of bytes in your answer

> This was inspired by [this CMC](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35411574#35411574) and [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109953/56656)

### Testcases

```
   Case   | Distance | Size of Neighborhood
--------------------------------------------
    ()    |    2     |         18
   ({})   |    2     |         33
   (())   |    2     |         32
    <>    |    4     |        186
   [][]   |    4     |        688
  <(){}>  |    4     |        1379
    {}    |    6     |        2270
  []{}[]  |    6     |        41097
```

Here are a few small examples with the actual neighborhoods included:

```
(), 2 :
{'', '<>', '()[]', '()()', '(())', '([])', '()<>', '{}', '{()}', '<>()', '(){}', '{}()', '<()>', '(<>)', '[()]', '[]()', '({})', '[]'}
```

---

```
({}), 2 :
{'([]{})', '()', '{}', '<({})>', '({<>})', '<{}>', '({()})', '(<>{})', '({}<>)', '({[]})', '(({}))', '({{}})', '({}[])', '{({})}', '({})()', '{}({})', '(())', '()({})', '([])', '<>({})', '({}{})', '({}){}', '({})<>', '(<{}>)', '({})[]', '((){})', '[{}]', '{{}}', '[]({})', '(<>)', '({}())', '([{}])', '[({})]'}
```

---

```
(()), 2 :
{'(())[]', '<>(())', '()', '{}(())', '{()}', '({()})', '{(())}', '(([]))', '(({}))', '(()[])', '(())<>', '((()))', '([])', '((<>))', '()(())', '(<()>)', '([()])', '[(())]', '(()){}', '(())()', '(()())', '(<>())', '(()<>)', '((){})', '<(())>', '<()>', '([]())', '(<>)', '({}())', '[()]', '({})', '[](())'}
```

---

```
<>, 4 :
{'<><<>>', '(<>)<>', '[<>][]', '<<><>>', '(){<>}', '(<>)()', '[<()>]', '<({})>', '<>()<>', '<[<>]>', '[][]<>', '<>[]<>', '<><><>', '[]<{}>', '[]<<>>', '[]<><>', '{<><>}', '[{<>}]', '<(<>)>', '(())<>', '{}<>{}', '()(<>)', '{()<>}', '(())', '{<>{}}', '(<><>)', '([])<>', '[]<[]>', '<{}<>>', '<><()>', '{()}<>', '{{}}<>', '{<>()}', '<<>>()', '{<<>>}', '<()>()', '<[]>()', '<>[<>]', '(<>())', '{}<>()', '(()<>)', '[{}]', '{{}}', '[]()', '[(<>)]', '<{}[]>', '<<>>[]', '{}<()>', '<>', '[()]<>', '<()><>', '[[]]<>', '[{}]<>', '[]<>[]', '()[<>]', '[]<>()', '{<>}{}', '{<[]>}', '<>(<>)', '(<>)[]', '<{}>()', '{}<><>', '{<>}()', '{[]}', '{[]}<>', '<<<>>>', '[]<()>', '<<[]>>', '<<{}>>', '[[]]', '()()<>', '[]{<>}', '<><[]>', '[[]<>]', '<{}()>', '<{<>}>', '<[]{}>', '{}<{}>', '<{}>[]', '()<<>>', '(<()>)', '[]{}', '{{}<>}', '{}()', '()<>[]', '<{}><>', '{[<>]}', '<><{}>', '<(())>', '<><>{}', '[()]', '<<>>{}', '{}{}<>', '[<<>>]', '<[][]>', '(<<>>)', '<[]><>', '[<>]<>', '[<>[]]', '[{}<>]', '{()}', '{<>[]}', '[]{}<>', '{(<>)}', '(<[]>)', '()[]<>', '<>{<>}', '{[]<>}', '(<>{})', '({}<>)', '[<><>]', '<><>()', '{}[<>]', '<{[]}>', '<<()>>', '<<>{}>', '([<>])', '<[]()>', '()()', '([])', '[[<>]]', '((<>))', '[](<>)', '(){}<>', '[()<>]', '<([])>', '<()()>', '[][]', '<<>[]>', '[<[]>]', '({})<>', '<{{}}>', '<[{}]>', '<{}{}>', '{}(<>)', '<<>><>', '[<>()]', '[][<>]', '({})', '{}[]<>', '{}<[]>', '<[()]>', '()[]', '<()>[]', '{{<>}}', '(<>){}', '{}{}', '({<>})', '{<()>}', '{}{<>}', '[]()<>', '<[]>[]', '(<>[])', '<[]>{}', '{}()<>', '()<[]>', '()<{}>', '{}<<>>', '<{}>{}', '{}[]', '()<>{}', '<()<>>', '[<>{}]', '{<>}[]', '<<>()>', '<><>[]', '{<{}>}', '<()[]>', '()<><>', '[<>]()', '()<>()', '{}<>[]', '<{()}>', '(<{}>)', '(){}', '()<()>', '<(){}>', '{<>}<>', '<[[]]>', '[]<>{}', '([]<>)', '<[]<>>', '[<>]{}', '<()>{}', '<>{}<>', '[<{}>]'}
```

Comment: Trying to make a Brain-Flak brute-forcer? :D

Comment: @mbomb007 I have taken into account all of your advice.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109953/34718) >:D

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37979/8478)

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, <strike>187</strike> 173 bytes

```
Length@Union@Select[""<>#&/@(Tuples[Characters@" ()[]<>{}",StringLength@#+#2]/." "->""),sFixedPoint[StringReplace["()"|"[]"|"{}"|"<>":>""],s]==""&&EditDistance[s,#]==#2]&
```

Brute force pure function. `#` represents the first argument (starting string) and `#2` represents the second argument (distance).

`Characters@" ()[]<>{}"` is the list of possible characters (including `" "`)

`Tuples[Characters@" ()[]<>{}",StringLength@#+#2]` is the list of all tuples of those characters with length at most the original string length plus the distance.

`Tuples[Characters@" ()[]<>{}",StringLength@#+#2]/." "->""` replaces all of the `" "` characters with the empty string.

`""<>#&/@(...)` joins all of those character lists into strings.

Next we `Select` all such strings which are balanced and which have the appropriate `EditDistance` with the following function:

```
s                                                                                                 String s
                                                                                                 maps to
  FixedPoint[StringReplace["()"|"[]"|"{}"|"<>":>""],s]                                              the fixed point of cancelling out pairs of brackets
                                                      ==                                             equals
                                                        ""                                          the empty string
                                                          &&                                        and
                                                            EditDistance[s,#]==#2                   the distance from s to # is #2
```

Next we use `Union` to delete the duplicates and take the `Length`.