# Count the size of the Levenshtein neighborhood

Tags: fastest-code, edit-distance

## Input

A binary string \$s\$ of length \$n\$ and a positive integer \$k \leq n\$.

## Output

The number of binary strings with [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) exactly \$k\$ from the string \$s\$.

## Example outputs

Each example gives the largest possible output for the given \$(n, k)\$ pair.

```
k=1, s=1010, output=14

k=2, s=1010, outupt=55

k=3, s=1101, output=112

k=4, s=1001, output=229

k=1, s=1010101010, output=32

k=2, s=1010110101, output=362

k=3, s=1010110101, output=2016

k=4, s=1011001101, output=6538

k=5, s=1011001101, output=16223

k=6, s=1001100110, output=37620

k=7, s=1001100110, output=85028

k=8, s=1001100110, output=187667

k=9, s=1001100110, output=406183

k=10, s=1001100110, output=864793

k=1, s=101010101010, output=38

k=2, s=101010010101, output=533

k=3, s=101010010101, output=3804

k=4, s=101001100101, output=15708

k=5, s=101100110010, output=45717
```

## Score

The score will be the highest \$n, k\$ pair your code outputs the correct answer for on my Ubuntu desktop in one minute.  The order should be (1,1), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1),(3,2), (3,3), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3), (4,4), (5,1) etc. The time is the total running time and not just for the last pair.

Your code should work for all strings but I will time it using random binary strings.

As always, this is a competition *per* language so Python coders don't need to worry about C competitors.

## Leaderboard

- **(28, 23)** in Rust by **Anders Kaseorg**
- **(12, 11)** in Rust by **corvus_192**.
- **(12, 10)** in Pypy by **Jonathan Allen**.
- **(11, 10)** in Pypy by **Value Ink**.
- **(11, 9)** in Python by **Value Ink**.
- **(11, 9)** in Python by **Jonathan Allen**.
- **(7,6)** in Charcoal **by Neil**.

## Edit

I noticed this [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238580/neighbourhood-of-a-word-and-levenshtein-distance) which has a link that suggests there is a fast algorithm

Comment: How is the highest (n,k) pair counted? Is it *total runtime* to generate up to (n,k) or is it *individual runtime* for the one (n, k) pair?

Comment: @ToAskOrNotToAsk It is the total runtime.

Comment: Is the alphabet limited to '0' and '1'?

Comment: @RootTwo Yes it is.

Comment: The rules assume that the chosen programming language can output partial results during computation, or that computation can be halted at one minute to get the results so far. There are languages where that is not easy, or not possible at all.

Comment: @doubleunary What sort of languages don't have loops where you can output something once a loop? Remember this is [tag:fastest-code]

Comment: To give an example, limited form first-order functional languages that aggregate output and only emit when finished. I think the challenge is solvable with a recursive lambda, but it is not easy to halt at a specified time limit.

Comment: @doubleunary Would it work to allow programs to achieve (n, k) if they can run up to that limit hardcoded within the program within the time allowed, if changing this limit theoretically allows correct answers for any inputs?

Comment: @xnor Sure, but that's not the rules specified in the question. I'm not going to participate in this one so no biggie personally.

Comment: Is there proof this hasn't poly-time solution?

Comment: @l4m2 Apparently not! https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/On-the-Levenshtein-Automaton-and-the-Size-of-the-of-Touzet/15e9e9aacc866c098140026001923a27747722f9  "Given a word P and a maximal number of errors k, we address the problem of counting the number of strings whose Levenshtein distance to P does not exceed k. We give an algorithm that scales linearly with the size of P and that is based on a variant of the classical Levenshtein automaton."

Comment: It’s linear in \$|P|\$ but exponential in \$k\$. “The downside of the method, however, is that it requires the computation of the DFA \$\mathrm{DULA}(k)\$, whose size increases exponentially with the number of errors \$k\$.”

Answer (score 8):

## Rust, score ≈ (28, 23)

The number of strings at distance \$k\$ from \$s\$ with some given prefix \$p\$ is a function of \$s\$, \$k\$, and the last column of the [Wagner–Fischer table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm) of \$s\$ and \$p\$. We use a recursive search on prefixes \$p\$, caching results based on this last column.

Build with `cargo build --release`, run with `target/release/levenshtein-neighborhood <s> <k>`.

**`Cargo.toml`**

```
[package]
name = "levenshtein-neighborhood"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
hashbrown = "0.14.0"
rustc-hash = "1.1.0"
typed-arena = "2.0.2"
```

**`src/main.rs`**

```rust
use hashbrown::hash_map::HashMap;
use rustc_hash::FxHasher;
use std::env;
use std::hash::{BuildHasher, BuildHasherDefault};
use typed_arena::Arena;

type Count = u64; // For n + k > 64, change this to u128
type Cache<'a> = HashMap<&'a [u8], Count, BuildHasherDefault<FxHasher>>;

fn count_state<'a>(
    target: &[bool],
    distance: u8,
    arena: &'a Arena<u8>,
    cache: &mut Cache<'a>,
    state: &mut [u8],
) -> Count {
    let hash = cache.hasher().hash_one(&state);
    if let Some((_, &count)) = cache.raw_entry().from_key_hashed_nocheck(hash, state) {
        count
    } else {
        let new_state = state;
        let state = arena.alloc_extend(new_state.iter().copied());
        let mut count = Count::from(state[target.len()] == distance);
        for symbol in [false, true] {
            let mut z = state[0].min(distance) + 1;
            new_state[0] = z;
            for (((o, &c), &x), &y) in new_state[1..]
                .iter_mut()
                .zip(target)
                .zip(&state[..state.len() - 1])
                .zip(&state[1..])
            {
                z = (x + u8::from(symbol != c)).min(y.min(z).min(distance) + 1);
                *o = z;
            }
            count += count_state(target, distance, arena, cache, new_state);
        }
        cache
            .raw_entry_mut()
            .from_hash(hash, |_| false)
            .insert(state, count);
        count
    }
}

fn count(target: &[bool], distance: u8) -> Count {
    let arena = Arena::new();
    let state = arena.alloc_extend((0..=target.len()).map(|i| (i as u8).min(distance + 1)));
    let mut cache = Cache::default();
    cache.insert(
        &arena.alloc_extend((0..=target.len()).map(|_| distance + 1))[..],
        0,
    );
    count_state(target, distance, &arena, &mut cache, state)
}

fn main() {
    if let [_program, target, distance] = &Vec::from_iter(env::args())[..] {
        let target = Vec::from_iter(target.chars().map(|c| c == '1'));
        let distance = distance.parse().unwrap();
        println!("{}", count(&target, distance));
    } else {
        panic!("usage: levenshtein-neighborhood <s> <k>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you modify it so that it runs on the 11001100... type strings so I can compare the outputs to the other answers?

Comment: @Simd It runs on any string you want, e.g., `target/release/levenshtein-neighborhood 1001100110 9`.

Comment: Unless I am running your code wrong, it seems to get way higher than 28, 27 and also suffers from overflow because of the huge counts.  I get to (37, 35) with https://bpa.st/ASBA

Comment: @Simd You'd have to change to `u128` for the count: https://github.com/jendrikw/levenshtein-neighbourhood/blob/main/src/main.rs

Comment: @corvus_192 Did you mean to link to a version using u128?

Comment: @Simd Your repeating 1100 strings are not the worst case for my algorithm. The score I quoted is for random input, on which it doesn’t get far enough to overflow. But you can just find-replace `u64` with `u128` if you want to score these easier inputs.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg That's very interesting. My intuition must be wrong for longer inputs. Repeating 1100 strings is close to the worst for the cases I have been able to check.

Comment: The output count for periodic and random inputs is about the same, but my running time is much faster for periodic inputs than random. I’m not stepping through all strings in the neighborhood one by one like the other answers, and periodic inputs give rise to a much smaller set of unique states I need to examine.

Comment: @Simd Sorry, wrong link. I added the u128 version in my repo: https://github.com/jendrikw/levenshtein-neighbourhood/blob/main/src/anders.rs

Comment: I can get to about (37, 31)

Comment: @corvus_192 See above comments. OP just edited the question to specify that benchmarking now uses random inputs.

Comment: Never knew of this approach to Levenshtein distance, great to learn!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), (11, 8); with Python PyPy (12, 10)

New version of [Value Ink's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265287/53748) using bit twiddling in place of string manipulation.

```python
from collections import deque

def countFixedDistance(s: str, k: int) -> int:
    n = int('1' + s, 2)
    distances: dict[int, int] = {n: 0}
    queue = deque(((n, len(s)),))
    valid: set[int] = set()
    while len(queue) > 0:
        current, bit_count = queue.popleft()
        next_dist = distances[current] + 1
        next_bit_count = bit_count - 1
        for next_gen in (
            ((current >> e + 1 << e) + current % (1 << e) for e in range(bit_count)),
            (current ^ (1 << e) for e in range(bit_count)),
            (((current >> e << 1 | b) << e) + current % (1 << e) for b in (0, 1) for e in range(bit_count + 1)),
        ):
          for next in next_gen:
              if next in distances: continue
              distances[next] = next_dist
              if next_dist < k:
                  queue.append((next, next_bit_count))
              else:
                  valid.add(next)
          next_bit_count += 1
    return len(valid)
```

**[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVRBbtswEDz05lfsJRAJy4ZU9BAItk9FX9Cb4Qa2tIoJK5RCUm6Kti_pJZfmI31F-5rukpIsGy4KhBdJ3J3ZWXJWP16aL25f6-fnn60rZ7d_3vwqTf0AeV1VmDtVawvqoamNgwIfW5xMCiwp2mr3QT1h8V5Zt9U5CpuBdSaGQwZKOwmzFT-zCdDSsOQPEaURTMHG8Fb6_aIDE7ZQuVtTTsyJG8r_qjNIvvs0KtsibXkBQggdQ4VaWCljGYiO20oVJAA9B8PpVYTY572q0AM8j4QVJEEWr7w1BrnsTrk73xaBfeK8qZsKy57G94FP7o5Fs5he-7qj2FBr6XnqmPP0PhullbUJqfeoqXMQQ4SXEB03rFaAzA-LBVAL01433IDoN5kLmcRs9T2KoSAd0zlrj_30CuyFJEKn8A128n_Cdr67JIb038W4wXFBmY1q9yfFuP7EsjNtAKocUkbWymvtlCbrniefLpAx7Jnheq_ThptfkMMv4oNH59umQV2QQyk9vvCAlBcwrCxeo_Jmnm-LwtOMURemmi47Jxl0rdHe4x4swyz_frHUVZREkyM9k0mYhI-m7crykR5O95D2YzVNRyffGJ5cESLxQcZXh98Hyqq1-yXzB9GWFUZpmiTR-njzbhNG9SQ7UNtObf8H-gs)**

---

With a lot of tweaks to do fewer operations, it does get further but still not to completion of (11, 9) on ATO, so it may also be worth benchmarking too:

```
from collections import deque

def countFixedDistance(s: str, k: int) -> int:
    n = int('1' + s, 2)
    distances: dict[int, int] = {n: 0}
    queue = deque(((n, len(s)),))
    valid: set[int] = set()
    while len(queue) > 0:
        current, bit_count = queue.popleft()
        next_dist = distances[current] + 1
        for e in range(bit_count):
            left = current >> e
            left_1 = left << 1
            pow = 1 << e
            right = current % pow
            bp1 = bit_count + 1
            for next, next_bit_count in (
                ((left >> 1 << e) | right, bit_count - 1),
                (current ^ pow, bit_count),
                ((left_1 << e) | right, bp1),
                (((left_1 | 1) << e) | right, bp1),
            ):
                if next in distances: continue
                distances[next] = next_dist
                if next_dist < k:
                    queue.append((next, next_bit_count))
                else:
                    valid.add(next)
        for next in (
            pow << 2 | current,
            3 << bit_count ^ current,
        ):
            if next in distances: continue
            distances[next] = next_dist
            if next_dist < k:
                queue.append((next, bit_count + 1))
            else:
                valid.add(next)
    return len(valid)
```

**[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVRBbtswEDz05lfsJRAJy4ZU9BAItk9FX9Cb4Qa2tIoJK5RCUm6Kti_pJZfmI31F-5rukpIsGy4KhBdJ3J3ZWXJWP16aL25f6-fnn60rZ7d_3vwqTf0AeV1VmDtVawvqoamNgwIfW5xMCiwp2mr3QT1h8V5Zt9U5CpuBdSaGQwZKOwmzFT-zCdDSsOQPEaURTMHG8Fb6_aIDE7ZQuVtTTsyJG8r_qjNIvvs0KtsibXkBQggdQ4VaWCljGYiO20oVJAA9B8PpVYTY572q0AM8j4QVJEEWr7w1BrnsTrk73xaBfeK8qZsKy57G94FP7o5Fs5he-7qj2FBr6XnqmPP0PhullbUJqfeoqXMQQ4SXEB03rFaAzA-LBVAL01433IDoN5kLmcRs9T2KoSAd0zlrj_30CuyFJEKn8A128n_Cdr67JIb038W4wXFBmY1q9yfFuP7EsjNtAKocUkbWymvtlCbrniefLpAx7Jnheq_ThptfkMMv4oNH59umQV2QQyk9vvCAlBcwrCxeo_Jmnm-LwtOMURemmi47Jxl0rdHe4x4swyz_frHUVZREkyM9k0mYhI-m7crykR5O95D2YzVNRyffGJ5cESLxQcZXh98Hyqq1-yXzB9GWFUZpmiTR-njzbhNG9SQ7UNtObf8H-gs)**

Comment: It seems to give 7 for countFixedDistance('10',1) where it should be 8

Comment: @Simd I used the same footer, I've updated to use `flush=True`. There was a bug in the second link which meant a prefix of `0` was not being applied for the insertions (in the `for next in (...` loop, which only handles the two prefix insertion cases) - `pow << 2 ^ current` was incorrect it should have been `3 << bit_count ^ current`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), ~(11,6)

Direct adaptation of my answer on [Pick a random string at a fixed edit distance](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264954/52194) with a minor optimization of generating the sets inline instead of each one being a function call. ATO seems to flip-flop between (11,6) and (11,7) for me right now.

```python
from collections import deque

def countFixedDistance(s: str, k: int) -> int:
  if k <= 0: return s

  chars: set[str]          = set('01')
  distances: dict[str,int] = {s: 0}
  queue                    = deque((s,))
  valid: set[str]          = set()

  while len(queue) > 0:
    current = queue.popleft()
    nextdist = distances[current] + 1
    for nxt in {current[:i] + c + current[i:] for c in chars for i in range(len(s)+1)} \
               | {current[:i] + c + current[i+1:] for c in chars for i in range(len(s)) if c != s[i]} \
               | {current[:i] + current[i+1:] for i in range(len(s))}:
      if nxt in distances: continue
      distances[nxt] = nextdist
      if nextdist < k:
        queue.append(nxt)
      else:
        valid.add(nxt)

  return len(valid)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNLbtswEF10R6B3mKwkwrIhZVUIcVZBTtCdqoVAUTFhhVT4SR0kPkk32bS7Hqg9TWco2g6atAgBQeDMmzeP8_n2Y3rwG6Ofn78HPyw__f7wcbDmFoQZRym8MtqBup2M9dDLuyAZ6-WA3qD9tdrJ_ko532khc1eD87aAbQ1Kew7LS_rXDEANsIWLNZQ1WOmD1eAYmsWmsxQkfYOBLRzPmmx5VlYZR1ifEiC0VyJiCyRuEfaItnKPGNQVJLxx1rPoPHcFJ7L7blT9v3Ny0vV1o0YJo9R5pOVwicoZgUSwVmqP4OhZTWYa5UBh5NVy50ksJT1oblJICwuoImowFvTOY23gMTmbWpFf0Jcsqm4jUhAuFipeFV1tp29kTvocX1R8D1_YX69--i_1ononOafOCTjD2jSqfVeeVzlek-7rRIPkqRAvWiyM9krjmM2YUyERSi0_FPkFx6HsFzh6R4Vzg7ppkrrPMZYnjxydPKHiOKy6PkHQngaUtEYnn7fi10-HybMyY3E53MNxKZzvTfBsHprPNhA7PXx7enhVwLFblHuyOL95qkex5cWb64QOEj3zr4YxuA0NmoMFCqmqsswaonHN8rxuCzjnLUvMLok-rPQf)

Comment: Changing `queue` from a deque into a list appears to be very slightly faster, although ATO's own variance might be messing me up.

Comment: Also, prefixes of `011001100110....` seem to have the biggest neighbourhood.

Comment: Upped to (10, 9) with inlining of the function calls with a little rearrangement of order and prefix/postfix variables [ATO (via tinyurl)](https://tinyurl.com/2p92tezb). (Does not look like the `c != s[i]`, or in my update `c != v`, is having much effect yet.)

Comment: (Oh and I switched to the prefixes Neil suggested in the footer)

Comment: you get to (11, 9) using pypy

Comment: @Neil That's not quite true as you can see from the example in the question.   But it is close.

Comment: @Simd Ah, so the best is to start with `01`, then alternate between `00` and `11`, and then end with `01` or `10` depending on which doesn't result in three identical digits in a row?

Comment: @Neil I am not sure it is that simple. See (12,3) where the best seems to be 101010010101. I would love to know if there is a simple pattern though. Obviously you can always take the bitwise complement but it still doesn't seem to follow your pattern.

Comment: @Simd It probably depends on `k`, so for instance (12,1) the best pattern is still `010101010101`, but the higher `k` gets, the more `00` and `11`s you need.

Comment: @Neil yes. If anyone can work out the pattern that would be great.

Comment: @Simd Best I can do is `k=1` no pairs; `k=2` or `k=3` one pair; higher numbers usually mean more pairs but sometimes you skip a number of pairs; no more than `n//2-1` pairs.

Comment: @JonathanAllan did you accidentally remove the inlining in that ATO link when you changed the test string to Neil's? It looks the same as my code. Regardless, I implemented inlining like you suggested.

Comment: Your code is much faster now but strangely isn't sped up much by pypy anymore.

Comment: @Simd maybe by inlining the set construction I inadvertently removed a function call bottleneck that pypy was optimizing around? lol

Comment: @ValueInk oops, sorry!

Answer (score 3):

## Rust, (12, 11)

This is basically a line-by-line port of Jonathan Allan's answer, with is already very good. Thanks! I wrote this to practice some Rust.

It uses the [nohash-hasher](https://crates.io/crates/nohash-hasher) crate for extremely fast HashMap lookups, with take up the vast majority of the time.

[Try it online on rustexplorer.com](https://www.rustexplorer.com/b#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). Runs an unoptimized debug build, so don't rely on it for measurements.

I have a [github repo](https://github.com/jendrikw/levenshtein-neighbourhood) with build instructions.

```rust
#![warn(clippy::all)]

use std::collections::VecDeque;
use std::collections::hash_map::Entry;
use std::time::Instant;

use nohash_hasher::{IntMap, IntSet};

fn count_fixed_distance(s: &str, k: u32) -> usize {
    let n = i32::from_str_radix(&format!("1{s}"), 2).unwrap();
    let mut distances = IntMap::with_capacity_and_hasher(1 << (s.len() + k as usize), Default::default());
    distances.insert(n, 0);
    let mut queue = VecDeque::from([(n, s.len())]);
    // capacity is just experimentation
    let mut valid = IntSet::with_capacity_and_hasher(1 << (k + 1), Default::default());
    while let Some((current, bit_count)) = queue.pop_front() {
        let next_dist = distances.get(&current).unwrap() + 1;
        let mut pow = 0;
        for e in 0..bit_count {
            let left = current >> e;
            let left_1 = left << 1;
            pow = 1 << e;
            let right = current % pow;
            let bp1 = bit_count + 1;
            for (next, next_bit_count) in [
                ((left >> 1 << e) | right, bit_count - 1),
                (current ^ pow, bit_count),
                ((left_1 << e) | right, bp1),
                (((left_1 | 1) << e) | right, bp1)
            ] {
                match distances.entry(next) {
                    Entry::Vacant(ve) => {
                        ve.insert(next_dist);
                    }
                    Entry::Occupied(_) => continue,
                }
                if next_dist < k {
                    queue.push_back((next, next_bit_count));
                } else {
                    valid.insert(next);
                }
            }
        }

        for next in [pow << 2 | current, 3 << bit_count ^ current] {
            match distances.entry(next) {
                Entry::Vacant(ve) => {
                    ve.insert(next_dist);
                }
                Entry::Occupied(_) => continue,
            }
            if next_dist < k {
                queue.push_back((next, bit_count + 1));
            } else {
                valid.insert(next);
            }
        }
    }
    valid.len()
}

fn main() {
    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut s = String::with_capacity(32);
    s.push('0');
    let mut v = 0;
    while s.len() <= 12 { // approx 2 minutes for profiling
        for k in 1..(s.len() + 1) {
            println!("{} {} {}", s.len(), k, count_fixed_distance(&s, k as u32));
        }
        s.push(['1', '1', '0', '0'][v % 4]);
        v += 1;
        println!("{}", s)
    }
    println!("{} seconds", start.elapsed().as_secs_f32());
}
```

Comment: What Cargo.toml do I need? I don't know rust.

Comment: I pushed my code to github: https://github.com/jendrikw/levenshtein-neighbourhood

Comment: I got it to work as you can see from the update to the question.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 81 bytes

```
⊞υη≔⦃η¹⦄ζＦＮ«≔υε≔⟦⟧υＦεＦΣ⁺Ｅκ⟦⭆κ¬⁼Ｉν⁼μξ⭆κ⎇⁼μξων⟧Ｅ²Ｅ⊕Ｌκ⁺⁺✂κ⁰ν¹λ✂κν¿¬§ζλ«⊞υλ§≔ζλ¹»»ＩＬυ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVG9TsMwEBZj8xSnTmfJlRLEgOhUIYZIUEUKW5UhTZ0f1XGKf6C0yspLsHQAwcQD8TTY-ZHKSfb58333-e78_p2VqcyalJ9On0bns-vfi7fIqBINhZLMvYVSVSHwWN5A0FI42Ku8kYCh2Bm9NPWaSSQEjt5kYNo8ZkkjXCUUjMNdFiPQ-djUGHGj8CHd4ZbCKtayEsWAlo3GuyeTcoW3qdIoCIUB1xT2xBqFfxmPTIpUvuI5i8ILBUFIYk-Odtm7UGSS1UxotsF7Jgpd4tbpdeV0W8yrjDlV3-ZTCGyQuwfHa0F6gyoHdLUudCg2bI8HR-yHMbR_HnFKdg6TcbrcodZrvcg2ovtOh4KMVZl_qHWmhk_5Wk1nz3ya_Fx5gR_4fuCWH_TBPw) Link is to verbose version of code. Can handle results of up to about `20000` on ATO, so `5 1011001101` or `4 101001100101`. Explanation:

```
⊞υη
```

Start with one string of distance `0`.

```
≔⦃η¹⦄ζ
```

Start with one string found so far.

```
ＦＮ«
```

Loop `k` times.

```
≔υε≔⟦⟧υＦε
```

Start collecting strings of distance `i+1`.

```
ＦΣ⁺Ｅκ⟦⭆κ¬⁼Ｉν⁼μξ⭆κ⎇⁼μξων⟧Ｅ²Ｅ⊕Ｌκ⁺⁺✂κ⁰ν¹λ✂κν
```

Loop over all strings of edit distance `1` from the current string of distance `i`.

```
¿¬§ζλ«⊞υλ§≔ζλ¹»
```

If this string is new then mark it as seen and add it to the list of strings of edit distance `i+1`.

```
»ＩＬυ
```

Output the count of strings of edit distance `k`.

Comment: Now you are challenging me to install charcoal! Remember this is [tag:fastest-code] so the score you should be quoting is the highest n, k you get to in one minute

Comment: @Simd I don't know what you mean by `n` in this context. If you set `k=1` then you can have a ridiculously long input string and it will still run in under a second. With `k=2` you can input strings of at least 75 and it will still run in under a minute. With `k=3` it starts struggling at length 25. And it can manage `k=6` if the string only has length 6.

Comment: Actually I can't count, it can manage `k=7` with a string of length `7`, but only just.

Comment: I fixed the order you have to consider the pairs. Thank you for pointing out the problem.

Comment: @Simd My [test suite](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VVFLbsIwEFWX5BQjVrbkSAn9qGpXiHaB1CIkukMsQjAkkmNoYpcUxEm6YdFK3fUOPUSl9jT1xE4AK_KM37z3PJ68fcZJlMfLSOz3H1rN_eu_s-91kgoOpC9XWo1UnsoFoRS2XqtbFOlCknE6YaDpbQNs0xsIdww2iM2XudMOdDbludPWXM2AI60xq72skFOo4khnZCh0QR6jFREMxrYRdxosFbl_1pEoSC8qFCkpA3eWDFbULAYniieeyyh_JccsBmsGJaUTkyGtY0NfxjnPuFR8Rh64XKiECPSr2qm2kUhjjq6B0TMITTHDC2u4pHZBOgeCvXZVX854STZIdPNwAzguoRVOojXURYKTyqrjzsNvaF6j7HNdV9pYmfqdzlYEk57gUY7Z7r2YxoX7oV_jtv8i2gzavi9Ve_L7E3ihF4R263hhlYZNfo57YKEAsRo04aICHd8qTHDlo_olxobYeDf2Yc09IV9Z9cG_1gWHvsLDLbU0sFr72n8) reaches `7,6` on ATO in just under a minute.